# Webots Visual Studio Cross-complitation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, webots

I'm writing a program for Webots in C++ in Visual Studio. I'm trying to cross-compile from the Webots software onto the e-puck1, but since I'm in VS it doesn't have the makefiles necessary to do so, as far as I know. I've tried to remake the controller within Webots with its makefiles, but I'm getting an error that it can't find my libraries.

[Links to my makefile and its error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1ak.jpg)

So my question(s) are these:

Can VS be used to cross-compile onto an e-puck?

If not, why can't my libraries be found by the makefile?

I've read through [this cyberbotics page](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/epuck#bluetooth-remote-control), but it wasn't telling me anything about my error, nor VS.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cross-compile, your makefile should contain at least this:

```
space :=
space +=
WEBOTS_HOME_PATH=$(subst $(space),\ ,$(strip $(subst \,/,$(WEBOTS_HOME))))
include $(WEBOTS_HOME_PATH)/projects/robots/gctronic/e-puck/transfer/libepuck/Makefile.include
```

Also using OpenCV on the e-puck1 is probably a very tricky process, you should have a version of OpenCV compiled for the e-puck robot.

About Visual studio, you will find more information here:

- https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-visual-studio-with-webots

Comment: Thanks for the VS info, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have anything about cross-compilation in there. Do have any idea why the makefile can't find my libraries? They're in the correct folders with the correct names.

Comment: You should try defining the 'LIBRARIES' and 'INCLUDES' variables before including the Makefile.include·